# Send non-DataContract class to Azure Service Fabric Actor

Tags: azure, serialization, datacontractserializer, azure-service-fabric

The Service Fabric requires `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes for all the classes that are used as input parameters for the Actor services.

Is there a way to override this default?

In our project we heavily use the read-only message classes, which have read-only properties and constructors. The serialization is handled by Newtonsoft JSON serializer, which works just great. Now, I want to send this messages in Service Fabric, so I need a way to override the default WCF-like serialization to something like JSON serializer.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make a workaround by implementing the serialization myself. Basically, this is how it works:

1. Define an actor (+ contract) which accepts and returns `byte[]` + type name, e.g.

   ```
   Task<byte[]> DoWork(string typeName, byte[] message);
   ```
2. Deserialize `byte[]` to an instance of the specified type by using custom serializer (I used Newtonsoft JSON converter).
3. On the sending side, serialize object to `byte[]` using the same serializer.

I defined some base classes to wrap that, so I don't have to repeat it for every actor / client.

This feels a bit hacky though. Would be nice to get some opinion from the Service Fabric team. Would be even nicer to get the native extensibility point from the platform itself. `DataContract` feels a bit archaic, it's not used anywhere in our project anymore.

This approach is described in more details in my [blog post](http://mikhail.io/2016/02/akka-net-style-actors-in-service-fabric/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible at the minute unfortunately. From [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-data-serialization/) article,

> "Reliable Collections allow the serializer to be overridden, but
>   Reliable Actors currently do not."

So it might be worth mapping to new classes.